# Using CSS '+' selector on siblings not working

Tags: html, css

I'm making a pure CSS animated navbar using the checkbox as a hamburger menu toggler, changing various elements with :checked and the + selector, which I've gotten to work on grand-child elements, but not siblings, I haven't found an adequate solution on the web either. Here's my HTML code, obviously stripped down a little:

```css
.toggler:checked+.menu {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-background"></div>
  <div class="menu-navigation"></div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
<div class="hamburger">
```

I got it to work on children of the hamburger class, so I'm fairy confident its an issue with the selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the checkbox input above the ".menu" class div. Then it will work fine.
I just added some background and text to show the result.
Hope this will help you

```css
    .menu {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .toggler:checked+.menu {
      width: 350px;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
    <div class="menu">
      abc
      <div class="menu-background"></div>
      <div class="menu-navigation"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hamburger">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `~` instead of `+` to see if it helps you

Comment: I did try using ~, it didn't seem to work. I read somewhere it's only for the next sibling not a previous one, which I suspect may be the reason

Comment: Yeah sure, if I remember well you can't use a selector to make changes to an element parent or a previous siblings. I suggest you use some javascript or jquery for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sibling selectors in CSS:

- `+` selects the next sibling and
- `~` selects any following sibling

As of now, there is no previous sibling selector in CSS, so you're going to have to change the order of your elements or use JavaScript.